# XPath Match br tags that does not have text before or after them in a tag

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have a requirement where I have to eliminate `<br>` tags enclosed in `<p>` tags whenever they are not preceded with text or followed with text, let me give a complete example.

**Asterisk (*)** tags are meant to be matched, the others are meant to be left untouched.

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <br/>*
    <span>Text1</span>
    <br/>
    <i>Text2    
    </i>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>
      <i>
        <br/>*
      </i>
    </b>
    <span>Text3</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Text4
    <i>
      <br/>*
    </i>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Text4</span>
    <br/>*
  </p>
</div>
```

Putting things simple, I need to normalize the text formatting from some Word documents where the editors were doing line-breaks act like paragraphs, line-breaks are meant to break text and not imply spacing between lines, this is the paragraph's job.
So, all I need is to keep `<br/>` tags surrounded by text safe and match the rest to issue a delete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use two queries:

```
//p/descendant-or-self::*/*[1     ]/self::br[not(preceding-sibling::node()/normalize-space()!='')]
//p/descendant-or-self::*/*[last()]/self::br[not(following-sibling::node()/normalize-space()!='')]
```

Comment: First query does not work completely, it still matches <br> tags not meant to be matched. Try it with:
`<p>
    <b>
      <br>
      Text 1
      <a>
        <br/>
      </a>
    </b>
  </p>` the second <br> is still matched tough it has text before him

Comment: Second query also does not work, it matches the middle <br> though it has text after, try with: `<div>
  <p>
    <b>
      <br>
      Text 1
      <a>
        <br/>
      </a>
      Text 2
    </b>
  </p>
</div>`.